# Looking for suggestions to get rid of inefficient for loop in raycasting

Tags: python, vtk, raytracing

I am currently working on a project to measure the volume of objects on a production line in real time using 3D depth cameras. There will be obfuscation and worse or better angles and therefore we want to simulate different camera configurations before we build a rig and test it in production. We have a large number of CT scans of these objects and based on these we want to simulate different camera views. What we want to simulate is a pointcloud as would be generated by a camera in a given position.

Every method I have found traces one ray at a time and you have to loop over the rays in a python loop. This is the slow part and I am looking for a method to get rid of this python loop. My intuition is that there should be a GPU accelerated library that can do this very quickly but I haven’t been able to find it, I usually do segmentation and registration of CT scans not 3d graphics. Below is a bit of detail on what I have tried so far.

I have a camera class. Of relevance for these calculations I have a source point self.pos and a plane of points I want to project to self.points_plane these are points in 3D space. So all the rays originate in self.pos and end at one of the elements in self.points_plane. My initial attempt was to use scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates:

```
for point in self.points_plane:
    dist = int(np.sqrt((self.pos[0]-point[0])**2+(self.pos[1]-point[1])**2+(self.pos[2]-point[2])**2))
    z_line = np.linspace(self.pos[0],point[0],dist)
    y_line = np.linspace(self.pos[1],point[1],dist)
    x_line = np.linspace(self.pos[2],point[2],dist)

    stack = ndimage.map_coordinates(array,np.vstack((z_line,y_line,x_line)),order=1,cval=-1000)
    # Hounsfield value check, air is -1000 and our objects are in the range -200:1000
    intersections = np.argwhere(stack > -500) 
    if intersections.size > 0:
         point_cloud.append([z_line[intersections[0][0]],y_line[intersections [0][0]],x_line[intersections [0][0]]])
```

It works, and the result looks nice but it’s too slow and we would be finished simulating next year… CuPy is a CUDA implementation of numpy/scipy and this was the next attempt since all the needed methods existed. Map coordinates was quicker but the transfer to GPU and back was slow and we still have a python loop. Not really a significant improvement, code is almost identical to the non-CUDA code.

I tried VTK.vtkOBBTree() and obbTree.IntersectWithLine() methods to see if this was a good solution and it is for small number of points. The IntersectWithLine method takes a starting and end point for each line and the checks for intersections with the obbTree generated from an STL file. The method is fast as long as we are not looping over too many points, at the scale we are working it would still take about a month to simulate the relevant data.

```
for point in self.points_plane:
    pointsVTKintersection = vtk.vtkPoints()
    obbTree.IntersectWithLine(self.pos, point,pointsVTKintersection,None)
    pointsVTKIntersectionData = pointsVTKintersection.GetData()
    noPointsVTKIntersection = pointsVTKIntersectionData.GetNumberOfTuples()

    if noPointsVTKIntersection > 0:
        point_c.append(pointsVTKIntersectionData.GetTuple3(0))
    self.point_cloud = np.array(point_c)
```

Any recommendations on how I can get rid of this for loop, is there a lib that does this in parallel for multiple rays?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [trimesh](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh) is faster on this, but probably worth trying.
I have an example [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/tree/master/examples/other/trimesh).

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion tried it out and ran a few test to see what it can do. it wasn't noticeably faster at first inspection and also i ran into an OOM error when trying on the highest resolution we want to simulate. Did at test on 10 camera angles at a lower resolution. The trimesh average time was 184.3 s while the vtk based average was 226.8s. For now our solution is just to skip on the highest resolution and the runtime of the simulations are workable with the trimesh solution but doesnt solve the original problem. Thanks for the suggestion.